# C++ Vector of abstract class of specific base class, as another class member

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, shared-ptr

I have:

1. A base abstract class `Shape`.
2. Then, several child classes, one of them, `Rectangle`.
3. A template class called `GeneralObject<T>`, having a private member `T` shape (`T` has a static assert check for being child of Shape), in order for a `GeneralObject` to be created: `GeneralObject<Rectangle>`
4. An `ObjectManager` which I want to include a vector of `GeneralObject`(s).

**How should I implement this functionality in order to have this vector of Template classes with arbitrary shapes?**

I suppose that one way is to remove the static assert from **3)** and create something like:

```
std::vector<GeneralObject <std::shared_ptr<Shape>>> objects;
```

but I am not sure if I am following the proper approach.
It would be great if I could also assert that the template function uses a child of Shape.

Comment: Ask yourself if you really need `GeneralObject` to be outside of the class hierarchy. If yes, `GeneralObject<T>` could have a pointer member `T*` (can also be a smart ptr). If you use `T` as a member you will likely run into slicing issues. Your vector would then just be of type `std::vector<GeneralObject<T>>`.

Comment: You can derive `GeneralObject<T>` from `GeneralObjectBase` and then have `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GeneralObjectBase>> objects;`.

Comment: @dtell Unfortunatelly I follow a specific design. I was indeed trying to avoid slicing issues and the need for this vector occured later on in the design, so that´s why initially the GeneralObject had a T instead of T*.
BTW, is there someone going around questions downvoting them? My question was not a lack of research, I have included a way that I thought is proper. My question shows lack of good c++ knowledge and your answers helped me understand a lot. Thanks

Comment: @Evg I would not add another inheritance if I can avoid it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the member of `GeneralObject` to be a pointer to `T` rather than `T`:

```
template<typename T>
class GeneralObject {
public:
  GeneraObject(std::shared_ptr<T> object) : object(object) {}

private:
  std::shared_ptr<T> object;
};
```

You can use this as

```
auto gObj = GeneralObject<Shape>(std::make_shared<Rectangle>());
```

Your container would then be

```
std::vector<GeneralObject<Shape>> objects;
objects.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>());
objects.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Circle>());
```

In summary something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Shape {
  virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

struct Rectangle : Shape {
  void draw() const override { std::cout << "Rectangular drawing\n"; };
};

struct Circle : Shape {
  void draw() const override { std::cout << "Circular drawing\n"; };
};

template <typename T>
class GeneralObject {
 public:
  GeneralObject(std::shared_ptr<T> object) : object(object) {}

  void draw() const { object->draw(); }

 private:
  std::shared_ptr<T> object;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<GeneralObject<Shape>> objects;
  objects.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>());
  objects.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Circle>());

  for (const auto& obj : objects) obj.draw();
}
```

This will output

```
Rectangular drawing
Circular drawing
```

Answer (score 1):

Two template variations with different template parameters are regarded as different classes. That's because the preprocessor copies the whole template code once for each variation but replaces the template parameter.

If you want to have a container with different objects of the same base template class you could use simple polymorphism.

Create a non-template base class for your `template GeneralObject` class and create a container holding pointers to this base class.

```
class GeneralObjectBase;
template<typename T> class GeneralObject : public GeneralObjectBase;

std::vector<GeneralObjectBase*> objects;
```

Comment: Instances of `GeneralObject<std::shared_ptr<Shape>>` can hold different most derived shapes each.

Comment: bipll - Also would be a good option. Really comes down to use case and preference